# Less recursion bug - calling recursive mixin contained in nested namespace from the containing namespace produces "is undefined"

Tags: recursion, less, mixins

The following code produces an error when compiled via Web Essentials for Visual Studio 2013. I think that plugin uses Winless but it has failed on other compilers as well.

```
.root {

    #namespace {

        .not-recursive(@x) {
            .margin-@{x} { margin: (1px * @x); }
        }

        .recursive(@x; @i: 0) when (@i =< @x) {
            .not-recursive(@i);
            .recursive(@x; (@i + 1) );
        }

    }

    /* This works */

    .sub-class {
        #namespace > .not-recursive(99);

        #namespace > .recursive(5);
    }

    /* Recursion fails */

    #namespace > .not-recursive(100);

    #namespace > .recursive(5);         // Why???

}
```

If I comment out the last line, with the comment `Why???`, it compiles.

If I place `#namespace` outside of `.root` and still use `#namespace > .recursive()` it compiles.

If I had to venture a guess I would guess that it is trying to call `.root .recursive()` rather than `.root #namespace .recursive()` once in the mixin, but this is merely a guess based on playing around and seeing what works/doesn't work.

This is not a big deal, but it's really bothering me and I want to know if I missed something in the docs or discovered a new issue.

Comment: I guess this is just a bug.

Comment: i suggest that the docs should mention that namespace should defined in the main scope.

Comment: @Bass Jobsen Well, no there's no such requirement. Namespaces can be defined anywhere (e.g. namespace inside namespace etc.). Technically a namespace is just plain ruleset and as any other ruleset it is allowed for infinite nesting.

Comment: Ah, the bug itself can be simplified to [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/814b47dc1550bfb23f7b) and therefor becomes [#996](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/996) (though there the example is a bit cluttered).

Comment: It seems like the developers could solve this by specifying a specific convention to follow (as @BassJobsen suggested for instance) but I guess they want to support nesting without any seemingly arbitrary restrictions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I do think it's a bug.
But after some tests ("Trial and Error") I found a working solution:

```
.root {
    (...)
    // Problem solved.
    & { #namespace > .recursive(5); }
}
```